# received email not recognized in my decorator. (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decorator

I'm getting an undefined local variable error within a decorator, and i'm not sure why. I will admit that this is the first time that i've used a decorator, therefore the problem could be within that as well.

I have a view that is rendered in a table format. Within that table I am showing specific emails that a user has received.  I am trying to use a decorator to limit who can see certain emails and such.  This is where the ultimate problem happens, in my view I am able to simply use `received_email.content` and i'm able to render the contents of the email. However I am not able to use that exact same approach in my decorator, I keep getting an `undefined local method or variable, received_email`.  I really do not know why this is the case as I assumed that by creating a decorator the same active record logic would be used within that.

Would anybody have any idea what this clueless newb here is doing wrong?

My controller is like so

```
class Admin::ReceivedEmailsController < Admin::ApplicationController
  load_resource :user
  load_and_authorize_resource :received_emails, through: :user, class: "AhoyMessage", parent: false

  def index
    @received_emails.decorate
  end
end
```

My view is like so (i didn't show all of it for brevity sake)

```
%td{nowrap: true}= received_email.sent_at.try(:to_formatted_s,:long)
%td= received_email.opened_at.try(:to_formatted_s,:long)
%td= received_email.clicked_at.try(:to_formatted_s,:long)
%td= received_email.decorate.content
/ %td= received_email.content
```

My decorator looks like so

```
class AhoyMessageDecorator < ApplicationDecorator
  delegate_all

  def content
    if context[:user] = (:is_admin?)
     received_email.content
    else
     "You need to have the correct admin access to view the email"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is received emails a collection?

Comment: oh, i'm sorry. Yes it is.

Comment: Are you using draper?

Comment: I am using the draper gem yes.

Comment: Does it work if you explicitly decorate the collection? i.e like `@articles = ArticleDecorator.decorate_collection(Article.all)`

Comment: I tried something related to that, however I was not able to get that to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your decorator has no way of knowing that outside it, you've named your variable `received_email`. Draper gives you access to the decorated object through `object` or `model`. Here's an example from [the README](https://github.com/drapergem/draper/blob/57a514133bc241e74cc4e8877d014cad4e1f12c6/README.md#accessing-the-model):

```
class ArticleDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  def published_at
    object.published_at.strftime("%A, %B %e")
  end
end
```